# How to simply calculate future value of periodic contributions to an index fund account?

Tags: equities, portfolio, index, return, annuity

So, for the sake of simplicity, ignoring taxes, expense ratio, volatility or anything else other than known values for the following five variables:

1. Starting contribution (dollars)
2. Annual contribution (dollars, deposited at the beginning or end of each period)
3. Starting price of one index fund share (example, VTSAX is currently $118.10)
4. Annual return of one index fund share (example, 10%, so in a year VTSAX would be $129.91 per share)
5. Number of periods (example, 30, as in years, to keep it simple)

Which is the most practical equation you know of that can be used to calculate the future value of contributions to an index fund account after n periods (say, 30 years)? The annuity (ordinary or due) formula gets me part of the way there but does not take share price into account. So I'm looking for a formula that does without requiring values for too many additional variables, if any. If there isn't an equation well-suited for this out there, I might think about deriving one. No formal finance training, self-taught as I go.

Thx,

Rec

Comment: This question appears to be more suitable for Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange forum.

Comment: ok thanks Alper, i'll post this question there as well

Comment: No problem. Note, however, cross-posting is discouraged in Stack Exchange forums. You can either wait for a moderator to migrate your post to that forum or  delete it here after posting it in that forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Long story short, the annuity formulas (ordinary or due) can in fact get the job done, whether the share price or the capital value of the account itself compounds at the annual return rate makes no difference. But it's still helpful to see how the number of shares increase over n periods.